# Why do I need to set XmlWriterSettings.Async to true to use async methods?

Tags: c#, async-await, xmlwriter

It's been a while since I last used `XmlWriter` but since today has been a lucky day to write some XML, so I started to use all the `...Async` methods by default but straight away I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Set XmlWriterSettings.Async to true if you want to use Async Methods.

It seems a bit weird to me that I have to set a flag on a settings object that I pass into the constructor of `XmlWriter` so that I can open up the use of methods on a class.

For example:

```
using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder))
{
    await xmlWriter.WriteStartElementAsync("", "root", "")
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Will throw an exception, however:

```
using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder, new XmlWriterSettings(){Async = true}))
{
    await xmlWriter.WriteStartElementAsync("", "root", "")
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Will work fine.

Does anyone know the reasoning behind this?

Comment: I could *guess*. If you look at the internals, you'll see that it returns a special [wrapper](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlAsyncCheckWriter.cs,6b9a7497731f9b46) when `Async` is true, which is making sure that only one activity is happening at a time. I guess deep in the guts there are some non-atomic uses of the `TextWriter` object so it has to protect access to it but they didn't want to incur the checking costs for existing code that wouldn't use any async methods.